# Change column value by row string value in R

Tags: r, rename

I'm having a problem with a set of data.
I want to change the values of a column, only for certain values in the rows of data.
My table has this structure:

```
  Var1   Var2
1   A    High
2   A    High
3   A    High
4   B    High
5   B    High
6   B    High
7   C    High
8   C    Low
9   C    Low
10  C    Low
```

Now, I want to change the "Var2" values to "Medium", only when Var 1 is C.
Thank you for help! :)
Alin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `d` is your data.frame:

```
d$Var2[d$Var1 == "C"] <- "Medium"
```

Comment: It returs me this message >> Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, d$Var1 == "C", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Make sure Var2 is `character`

Comment: Yes. It's wasn't character.

Comment: .@Thomas - Why performing this `d[10,"Var1"] <- 0` on above data gives me `Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`. The value instead of being `0` changes to `NA` for the specific cell. Any suggestions please.

Comment: I tried a similiar approach for my problem here and wrote `dat$participant[dat$date== "2020-06-07_12h33.46.880"] <- "101"` But it didn't work. What am I missing? date and participant are characters https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62376988/rename-value-for-multiple-rows-based-on-other-variable

Answer (score 1):

try

`d$Var2[d$Var1 == "C", ] <- "Medium"`

There has to be a comma after the condition.
This is a R-specific thing.