# rename value for multiple rows based on other variable

Tags: r, rename

I've got a data frame with multiple rows for each participant. There is an error in some of their ids (for example, some are double). I wanted to assign them a new one like this

```
dat[dat$participant == "36" & dat$date == "2020-06-07_12h33.46.880"] <- "101"
```

I get the error message "duplicate subscripts for columns". 
Whats wrong with my command?

I also tried

```
dat$participant[dat$date== "2020-06-07_12h33.46.880"] <- "101"
```

with no error but also no participant with these value appearing

Answer (score 0):

The error `duplicate subscripts for columns` tells you here that you are trying to assign a value to a nonsensical part of dataframe. So you need to use `dat$participant` rather than only `dat`.

Generally speaking, you can use this command:

```
dat$participant[some condition] <- "101"
```

E.g. modifying your first command:

```
dat$participant[dat$participant == "36" & dat$date == "2020-06-07_12h33.46.880"] <- "101"
```

But there can be another problem, e.g. make sure you provide correct date (copy and paste the value, as there are many types of [hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen) and [dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)) which can occur in dirty data, maybe the IDs are not characters but numbers, etc.

So if you want more concrete help, provide here a few lines of your data frame.